# Databricks Files System: How to count files in as folder by using notebook

Tags: python-3.x, databricks, azure-databricks

**Question**: [This document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/databricks-utils#--file-system-utility-dbutilsfs) from Azure Databricks describes tasks you can perform on a `Databricks File System [DBFS]` using [dbutils](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/databricks-utils#--file-system-utility-dbutilsfs). Is there a simple method to find total number of files in a folder inside `DBFS`?

Answer (score 2):

you can use both ways to get the count values:

**Option1:**

`dbutils.fs.ls()` returns the file info for all the files present in the specified path as a list.

using len() on this returned list to get the count of files in that path

```
 len(dbutils.fs.ls('/FileStore/tables/'))
```

**Or**

**Option2:**

```
import os
paths =os.listdir('/dbfs/FileStore/tables')

print(len(paths))
```

**Updated:**

This code will return only count of files present in the path.

```
import os
contents = os.listdir('/dbfs/FileStore/tables')
cnt=0
for content in contents:
#Concat file name and path to check if it is a file name or not. 
    if(os.path.isfile('/dbfs/FileStore/tables/'+content)):
        cnt+=1
print(cnt)
```

Comment: Both options are returning subdirectory names , as well

Answer (score 1):

Glob's file matching patterns can be also helpful to pinpoint certain file types or avoid listing directory names:

```py
from glob import glob
len(
    glob("/dbfs/mnt/raw/datasource/dataset/*.parquet")
)
```

`Out[17]: 47`

Also, it has optional recursive search: `recursive=True`